# Need help proving an equality

Tags: arithmetic

I'm looking for help proving this equality:

> $\forall m:m \times 0 = 0 = 0 \times m$

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: It all depends on what properties of $\mathbb N$ you are allowed to use? How is multiplication defined in your context?

Answer (score 3):

This is assuming that you know **distributivity** and that $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}, n + 0 = 0 + n = 0$.

\begin{align}
0 &= 0\\
0 &= 0 + 0\\
a \cdot 0 &= a \cdot (0 + 0)\\
(a \cdot 0) &= (a \cdot 0) + (a \cdot 0)\\
\color{blue}{-(a \cdot 0) + (a \cdot 0)} &= (a \cdot 0) + \color{blue}{(a \cdot 0)+ -(a \cdot 0)}\\
0 &= (a \cdot 0) + 0\\
0 &= a \cdot 0
\end{align}

Commutativity then implies that $0 = a \cdot 0 = 0 \cdot a$.